# Mocking a Faraday::Response object's `body`, and Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Tags: unit-testing, xml-parsing, nokogiri, faraday

When trying to mock a `Faraday::Response` object, I've tried:

```
mock(Faraday::Response, :env => {:body => "...some xml..."})
```

...but this fails when I call `response.body.xpath(...)`, because the body is a String, and it's expecting a NodeSet.

Is there an easy way to convert an arbitrary XML string into a NodeSet? I've read through the [Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) docs, but it's either not there, or I'm missing it.

**Here's my actual stub+mock:**

```
@conn.stub!(:get).and_return(mock Faraday::Response,
      :env => {:status=>207},
      :body => '<scheduled-calendar xmlns="[removed]" xmlns:xsi="[removed]" id="95ec6d99-2c4a-4e25-99a1-2e988c0dbce6" assignment-id="uuid_for_test" xsi:schemaLocation="[removed]" debug="true">
                <scheduled-study-segment id="4e5b24e3-b50a-45e2-aec1-cb6c839a20f1" start-date="2012-01-06" start-day="1" study-segment-id="524910e9-634a-4791-a0b2-90f506a86474">
                <scheduled-activity id="1caa08b2-acb0-4c93-8c76-6460f0e9ee09" ideal-date="2012-01-06" details="Screening survey" repetition-number="0" planned-activity-id="1fc520dd-5b6f-4125-b83c-2f8801ea3065">
                <current-scheduled-activity-state reason="Initialized from template" date="2012-01-06" state="conditional"/>
                </scheduled-activity>
                </scheduled-study-segment>
                </scheduled-calendar>'
    )
```

**Here's the call to `xpath`**

```
response.body.xpath('//psc:scheduled-activity', Psc.xml_namespace).collect{|activity| activity.attributes["id"].value}
```

**And here is the test failure:**

```
NoMethodError in 'PscV1 should allow you to get a list of scheduled activity ids for a given involvement'
undefined method `xpath' for #<String:0x10dad1818>
```

Comment: "Hey! Response! You look more like a request to me!" ;)

Comment: Except, if I remove the mock and have it actually hit the API live, I get back a `Faraday::Response` object, which is why I'm mocking that object. Am I missing something important there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, essentially the answer turned out to be that Faraday wasn't treating my body as XML, and as a result, just passed the response back as a String, instead of a [Nokogiri::XML::Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

By doing...

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML('<scheduled-calendar xmlns="[removed]" xmlns:xsi="[removed]" id="95ec6d99-2c4a-4e25-99a1-2e988c0dbce6" assignment-id="uuid_for_test" xsi:schemaLocation="[removed]" debug="true">
            <scheduled-study-segment id="4e5b24e3-b50a-45e2-aec1-cb6c839a20f1" start-date="2012-01-06" start-day="1" study-segment-id="524910e9-634a-4791-a0b2-90f506a86474">
            <scheduled-activity id="1caa08b2-acb0-4c93-8c76-6460f0e9ee09" ideal-date="2012-01-06" details="Screening survey" repetition-number="0" planned-activity-id="1fc520dd-5b6f-4125-b83c-2f8801ea3065">
            <current-scheduled-activity-state reason="Initialized from template" date="2012-01-06" state="conditional"/>
            </scheduled-activity>
            </scheduled-study-segment>
            </scheduled-calendar>')
```

And then passing that `xml` variable in as the body...

```
@conn.stub!(:get).and_return(mock Faraday::Response,
  :env => {:status=>207},
  :body => xml
)
```

...the issue was resolved.